# Retrieving response from a php url in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have created an api. Lets say this is my php url

```
"http://xxxxxxx/game/game.php?validate=yes&email=myEmail@mars.com"
```

The response of this query is either 1 0r 0. It validates the email if it exists in db or not. I have been searching but failing till now, How am i suppose to send it to server. By NS URL or I have to use `NSURLConnection`. How in turn I can read the response.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxx/game/game.php?validate=yes&email=myEmail@mars.com"]];
```

[Bible, Old Testament.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

[Bible, New Testament.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Edit: so the response is XML? Right. (No, not right, you should really consider using JSON, but anyways...) You can use the [NSXMLParserClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get back the response in this case. Especially have a look at its `- initWithContentsOfURL:` method.

Comment: @H2CO3 The response is in xml format. I am sorry for mistakenly saying that its either 1 0r 0